# Spring Controller - Fill DTO from Servlet Request manually

Tags: spring-mvc, controller

In Spring controller, I want to invoke same method for different HTML - Forms submission
So, taking HttpServletRequest as a RequestBody

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Search")
public String doSearch(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, ModelMap map) {
    // Now, looking for something like this...
    if(req.getType.equals("x")
        //X x = SOME_SPRING_UTIL.convert(httpServletRequest,X.class)
    else
       // Y y = SOME_SPRING_UTIL.convert(httpServletRequest,Y.class)
}
```

I want to convert request parameters to bean through Spring, As it converts while I take Bean as method argument

Comment: Why? Why not simply create multiple methods and differentiate the mapping. How do you determine which object to create?

Comment: Based on Action Id/Type which can be derived from request parameter

Comment: It's really unclear to me what you are trying to do...

Comment: Then use that request parameter to differentiate the mapping. Use the `params` attribute to differentiate and let Spring do the heave lifting.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `params` attribute of the `@RequestMapping` annotation to differentiate the request mapping mapping.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/search", params={"actionId=Actionx"})
public String searchMethod1(X search) {}

@RequestMapping(value="/search", params={"actionId=ActionY"})
public String searchMethod2(Y search) {}
```

This way you can create methods for each different action and let spring do all the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: That is completely fine, but can we have common method as I can handle things by generic approach

Comment: Why do you want to do all things by hand? Why don't you simply utilize the framework? But alas if you must, annotate a String method parameter with `@RequestBody`, not sure why you want to have 1 large I can handle the whole world method...